# css animation on scroll up and down

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am trying to get my images to trigger a bounceInLeft after loading which works fine but I want to use jQuery to trigger a shake effect on scroll. I am following this tutorial on youtube http://youtu.be/CBQGl6zokMs It doesn't seem to be working correctly, if you can help please do so.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Divs Galore</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  
 </head>
 <body>

  <div>
      <img src="jennah.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="jennah.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="jennah.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="jennah.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
      <img src="jennah.jpg">
  </div>
   <input type="img">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
   $('img').on('scroll',function() {
    $.addClass('animated shake');
  });

  })
   
   
  </script>

  
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have JQuery loaded, add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your head section.

Additionaly, from what I have just tried, the onscroll event only occurs if an actual scrolling happens, so it's not fired on every mouse wheel (there is a "mousewheel" event for that). You should also assign the event to the window, not the input:

```
<input id="myinput">

...

window.onmousewheel = function() { $('#myinput').addClass('animated shake')};
```

Comment: I edited the code to include what it looks like now. Of course its still not working but just want to know if anyone could advise me based on the edited code. Thanks for yours and anyone elses help in advance